# Python base64 encoding a string with accents (special characters)

Tags: python, base64

being Portuguese, I often get accents and other special characters in my text strings.
The code below works fine for a file with no such characters:
note: testfile.xxx is not a txt file but can be opened with notepad and shows utf-8 encoding

```
 `with open(testfile.xxx, "r") as my_file:
        my_text = my_file.read()       
        my_bytes = my_text.encode('ascii')
        my_base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(my_bytes)
        encoded_string = my_base64_bytes.decode('ascii')`
```

If i add a "Ç" it fails on the "encode('ascii')
but if I add an "Á" it fails even earlier, on the my_file.read

How can I overcome this? I suppose there's no One solution fits all and I would have to know in advance what the encoding of my file is (utf-8 vs ANSI)

I need this to send my byte array to a SOAP Request.

Thanks

Comment: If the file contains accented characters and "can be opened with notepad and shows utf-8 encoding" then it seems like you should replace `encode('ascii')` with `encode('utf8')` a̶n̶d̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶`̶d̶e̶c̶o̶d̶e̶`̶?

Comment: @Anentropic The base 64 encoded string will only contain ASCII characters, so the `decode` is fine. But yeah, if you have UTF-8 text, treat it as UTF-8…!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file contains UTF-8 encoded text, then open it using that encoding:

```
with open(testfile.xxx, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as my_file:
```

This will ensure the content is correctly *read* from the file in the first place. If you then want to convert it to `bytes`, you need to choose an encoding that can represent all the characters in it. So not ASCII, but, well… UTF-8 would be a good candidate:

```
my_bytes = my_text.encode('utf-8')
```

Or you forgo all that and just read the raw bytes from the file without any de- and re-encoding:

```
with open(testfile.xxx, 'rb') as my_file:
                         
    my_bytes = my_file.read()       
    my_base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(my_bytes)
    encoded_string = my_base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Actually I ended up complicating by changing two lines at once on my original code. This issue originated because when my files have accents, they usually had to be saved with ANSI encoding or else they would be changed to other characters, on opening. But now, somehow, I added the accented characters, saved and it opens just fine with accent...in utf-8 !! There's something here that I'm missing, but it works just fine.

Comment: You may be interested in: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). If you save it and it screws up when opening it again, that probably means the program you're opening it with is choosing the wrong encoding to read the file.

Comment: Very interesting reading, indeed. I assume you are calling me "Anonymous code monkey" because that's more or less what happened. We get these files with .EUR extension that contain...well, text. They are output of all sorts of company HR/financial software that usually don't have accented letters in names in the first place. But every once in a while, someone just writes it all in Excel and exports it and voilá: ANSI encoded. That gives garbled letters and two character counts on that line instead of one, completely messing up my RPA workflow.

Comment: Yeah, ideally you'd be able to dictate the encoding that you accept. If not and you just get random encodings thrown at you, the first step is to check if the file is valid in a certain encoding, i.e. it would raise errors if you tried to read it as UTF-8 but it's not actually valid UTF-8. The problem with ANSI encodings is that they're all single byte, where any byte is valid, so they can't be "invalid". In that case you need human intervention to check using which encoding the characters show up correctly. Or you need [tag:nlp] libraries that try to sanity check that.

Comment: That's more or less what I have. I mimic "human intervention" in the RPA by opening the file and checking the encoding. Then I re-open the the file using the encoding I got in the previous step thus assuring I get every character as sent. thanks